# Ubuntu Distutils and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

On an Ubuntu 20 LTS system (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS), just upgraded from 18.04 LTS
and running Pycharm 2020.2.3  professional (re-installed several times since upgrade of Ubuntu, via snap).

Checking that I have distutils installed:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall python3-distutils
```

Gives the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to reinstall, 0 to remove and 11 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/141 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 397429 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distutils_3.8.5-1~20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.8.5-1~20.04.1) over (3.8.5-1~20.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.8.5-1~20.04.1) ...
```

At the bash command line:

> pip3 --version

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Within pycharm, creating a new project executes the following command:

> /snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip
> install --no-index
> /snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

This fails, indicating that the it "Failed to create interpreter"
giving the following output...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

I also tried uninstalling using

> sudo snap remove pycharm-professional

Then re-installing using the toolbox -- and I got the same errors.

How can I get Pycharm to start using the installed version of distutils or it's own version so I can get back to developing with this IDE?
Or doesn't Pycharm function with Ubuntu 20 LTS?

Thanks for your help

Comment: snapped PyCharm can be tricky to get working properly.  My advice would be to install PyCharm using the Jetbrains Toolbox (NOT via the snap versions!) and then you will have full access to Python on your system.  I've had issues getting the snapped versions to work, but no problem with the Toolbox / Tarball versions direct on-system.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Ward ...i just took your advice, but to no avail.  First I uninstalled using: sudo snap remove pycharm-professional, then re-installed using the toolbox. Same error.

Comment: was the Toolbox installed as a snap too?

Comment: Not sure.  However I know that by changing the interpreter of the project to python3.8 from the \user\bin\python3.8 and creating a new virtual environment, the issue I now have is different. I've just lost all of my libraries. I'd rather just go back and use the previous environment, or at least have the modules available. Also, kicking off the python console gives me:    File "<input>", line 1
    \%load_ext autoreload
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax